# git when changing the repository

Tags: git, repository

I am used to pull from a git repository of someone. Today he moved his repository to another address. I wonder if there is some way for me to pull from the new address and to get the info of what changes he made with respect to last time before his moving?

What I have done is "git clone newaddress" under my repository pulled from his old one. The output is like:

> got xxx
>
> walk xxx
>
> got xxx
>
> got xxx
>
> walk xxx
>
> Getting alternates list for newaddress
>
> Getting pack list for newaddress
>
> Getting index for pack xxx
>
> Getting pack xxx
>
> which contains xxx
>
> got xxx
>
> got xxx
>
> walk xxx
>
> ...

Then I "git pull" and got the following message which I don't understand:

> You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
> want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in
> your configuration file does not tell me either.  Please
> name which branch you want to merge on the command line and
> try again (e.g. 'git pull  ').
> See git-pull(1) for details on the refspec.
>
> If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
> configure the following variables in your configuration
> file:
>
> ```
> branch.master.remote = <nickname>
> branch.master.merge = <remote-ref>
> remote.<nickname>.url = <url>
> remote.<nickname>.fetch = <refspec>
> ```
>
> See git-config(1) for details.

What can I do now to still be able to get the info of what changes he made with respect to last time before his moving?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you are looking to do is replace your current remote origin with a new one. I don't know if you can replace it from command line, but you can change it in your `.git/config` (this is in your project directory)

OLD

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git+ssh://original_repository.com/my_project.git
  ...
```

NEW

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git+ssh://new_repository.com/my_project.git
  ...
```

The `git+ssh` part might be something like `git@` (this is what it would be if you were using github), or I'm sure a variety of other things. This might help clear up some things that I left out or didn't explain well enough: [Changing Your Origin](http://github.com/guides/changing-your-origin).

Hope this helps answer your question. Cheers.

Comment: For quick ref :----------------------------- git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo2.git  -----------------------------------------  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your cloned git repository:

```
 git config branch.master.remote origin
```

to take care of the "You asked me to pull without telling me"... message.

Then, if you know where the remote repo was moved, you could do in your new cloned local repo a `git diff` since that date.

```
$ git diff "@{yesterday}"
$ git whatchanged --since="2 weeks ago"
```

Note: the upcoming [git1.6.5 mentions](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/128351)

> Human writable date format to various options, e.g. "`--since=yesterday`", "`master@{2000.09.17}`", are taught to infer some omitted input properly.

See also the SO question "[How do you get git to always pull from a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161609/in-git-how-can-i-get-the-diff-between-all-the-commits-that-occured-between-two-d)"

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I did something terribly wrong here. I cloned his new repository right under the directory of my own one, which means a clone of his new repository appears as a subdirectory of my own one, a clone of his old repository. So I just removed the whole subdirectory. Now if I do a "git clone newaddress" under the parent directory of my repository, I will get "fatal: destination directory 'vision_test' already exists." So now what is the correct way to change the address of his repository in my own one so I can only use "git pull" in the future? Thanks and regards!

Comment: In git 1.7.7.5, I had the "You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you ..." after calling `git remote rm origin` and `git remote add origin git@fluff:/git/dist.git` .  But I had to call the following 3:
1) `git config --remove-section branch.master`
2) `git config branch.master.remote origin`
3) `git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master` to get rid of the warning and not have two [branch "master"] in ./git/config .