# How to 'git push' to a repo that was cloned as read-only onto my team's staging server

Tags: git, github, staging

I cloned a repo using its GitHub read-only URL onto my team's staging server.  I made some changes there to the config files.

I'd like to change the repo clone on the server to be read-write, so that I can 'git push' the config file changes.

How do I do this?

Or is there a better 'best practice' way to deal with this scenario than committing from the staging server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

open up .git/config in your favorite text editor and change the remote url to the read+write url that github shows you.

Comment: This is the canonical solution. If you're sure you want your stage server to have push access to the github repo, you probably want to do this. It's a very simple change.

Answer (score 4):

if you only want to set the push url you can use the --push option

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:leo/repox.git
```

Answer (score 1):

From [GitHub Working with remote](http://help.github.com/remotes/) help page:

> Changing a remote’s URL
>
> There is no direct command to change a remote’s URL, so you will usually run `git remote rm` followed by `git remote add` to change a URL.
> You can also edit the repo’s `.git/config` file directly to change the URL without re-fetching the remote.

I would recommend (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)):

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Using git command is always preferable to modifying directly a git config file manually.

Comment: It's not preferable to me because it's more junk I have to remember (unnecessarily) and is less direct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a diff from the staging server and apply it in a development environment via `patch(1)`.