# Gitolite: git push origin master fails with "fatal: The remote..."

Tags: git, push, gitolite

We have a new gitolite server where I work, and I'm having trouble push a repo to the server.

I cloned the conf file, added my repo, then pushed it back.  After confirming that the empty repo is there I clone the repo to my computer.  I get an error that says, warning you've cloned an empty repo.  So to test this I add a README, and commit it.  No problem.  But when I try to push it back to the server with the change I get a `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`.

It may also be of note, but when I'm working in a repo, I have a little script for my prompt that tells me when the repo isn't pushed... this isn't present here.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

- your `HOME` environment variable is defined
- your public key is in `%HOME%/.ssh` (or `$HOME/.ssh` on Unix)

The trick with gitolite is that the public key is named after your name.
Ie it is not named after the default public key name (id_rsa.pub)

In that case, you need an ssh config file to specify the name of the private (and public by extension) key:

```
$ vi ~/.ssh/config

host gitolite
     user git
     hostname yourgitserver.com
     identityfile ~/.ssh/mypubkey
```

Then [change your remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git):

```
git remote set-url orgin gitolite:your-project
```

And try to push. It should work then.