# How to access git remote repo since IP address changed

Tags: git, cloud, ip-address, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change a remote repository URI using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

I have 2 remote repos

```
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Originally these were on `ip-address-1`.  The ip address has changed to `new-ip-address-2`.

How can I change my local references so I can access the same repo at a new ip address?

Comment: If you use a DNS name rather than an IP address for your Git URL, you won't run into this kind of issue.  You can edit the URLs in .git/config.

Comment: Change it in the .git/config file of your projects root directory.

Comment: @vcsjones is correct... what is the proper thing to do on my side?  delete?  answer with same answer?  close?  Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherIckes Flag it as a dupe to that link. Either the community will close it as a duplicate or a diamond mod will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make changes in your hosts file and force DNS resolution (old DNS to new ip, I'm using 192.168.0.2 as example)

```
192.168.0.2 old.dns.entry
```

This is not the best solution but works in some environments.

Comment: Yikes, no, don't do this.  Never make your hosts file lie about DNS entries on the live internet, you absolutely will regret it.

Comment: I bet with You about activate.adobe.com ping results on your friends laptops. Let me know how many people returns the right ip address which is not 127.0.0.1 :)

Comment: @fab23 I see what you did there...