# Change the repo initialized folder

Tags: android, git, repository

I would like the repo to sync the source code to "~/home/username/android/device/" folder
currently the repo sync checks out to "~/home/username/" folder

I have tried to initialize the repo to /android/device folder twice and then synced it again, however it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use git remote set-url? If not, you may find helpful this article: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like to set the local working folder.

Comment: Then you may want to edit your .git/config file if you already didn't. Check the following question on stackoverflow, maybe you'll find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git