# How to remove remote origin from a Git repository

Tags: git, git-remote

I just did `git init` to initialize my folder as Git repository and then added a remote repository using `git remote add origin URL`. Now I want to remove this `git remote add origin` and add a new repository `git remote add origin new-URL`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2796, accepted):

Instead of removing and re-adding, you can do this:

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

See this question: [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

To remove remote use this:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Comment: @acannon828, the protocol necessary depends on how you're connecting to git. The example provided assumes you are using the git protocol. The [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) explains various protocols supported by git.

Comment: This is the correct answer, there is some confusion caused by the phrasing of the title and the question itself.

Comment: If you use Bitbucket instead of github you will delete the first "git://" part and directly write git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/reponame.git and of course change the place holders : "yourusername" and "reponame" with yours.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, the correct answer is:  git remote set-url origin new.url.here. Having git:// will just cause a fatal error. Not sure why this was in the answer.

Comment: If you are working on a separate repo that requires a separate ssh key and are running into similar issues, it's possible your issue may not be git remote origin related. If this is the case, you may have to add your new key into your key list. Checkout this answer for help if you're in this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927914/git-error-please-make-sure-you-have-the-correct-access-rights-and-the-reposito/30935242#30935242

Comment: That surely worked for me without any doubt! Thanks man!

Answer (score 815):

If you insist on deleting it:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Or if you have Git version 1.7.10 or older

```
git remote rm origin
```

But [kahowell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330439/1615903) is better.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question "how to remove remote origin from git repo".

Comment: What if I have multiple URLs associated with origin, but only want to remove one of them?

Comment: @Michael what exactly do you mean by _"multiple URLs associated with origin"_? How is the remote configured?

Comment: @Michael You can achieve that using `git remote remove <name>` where `name` is the repo name, not the full URL

Comment: `rm` in `git remote rm` works in every git version I think, not just in old ones <2.

Answer (score 118):

To remove a remote:

```
git remote remove origin
```

To add a remote:

```
git remote add origin yourRemoteUrl
```

and finally

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 52):

if multiple remotes are set for a project like heroku and own repository then use the below command to check the available remote URLs inside the local project directory

```
git remote -v
```

it will display all the remote URLs like

```
heroku  https://git......git
origin  https://git......git
```

if you want to remove heroku remote then,

```
git remote remove heroku
```

it will remove heroku remote only if want to remove own remote repository

```
git remote remove origin
```

Answer (score 48):

you can try this out,if you want to remove origin and then add it:

```
git remote remove origin
```

then:

```
git remote add origin http://your_url_here
```

Answer (score 41):

I don't have enough reputation to comment answer of @user1615903, so add this as answer: 
"git remote remove" does not exist, should use "rm" instead of "remove".
So the correct way is:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Comment: `remove` was added in 1.7.12. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 32):

To remove just use this command

```
git remote remove origin
```

Add new

```
git remote add origin (path)
```

Comment: just make sure to keep checking your current remote repository address using "git remote -v" otherwise you might end up removing the wrong remote repository.

Answer (score 25):

You can rename (changing URL of a remote repository) using :

```
git remote set-url origin new_URL
```

new_URL can be like https://github.com/abcdefgh/abcd.git

Too permanently delete the remote repository use :

```
git remote remove origin
```

Answer (score 20):

To set a origins remote url-

```
   git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

here origin is your push url name. You may have multiple origin. If you have  multiple origin replace origin as that name.

For deleting Origin

```
   git remote rm origin/originName
   or
   git remote remove origin/originName
```

For adding new origin

```
   git remote add origin/originName git://new.url.here / RemoteUrl
```

Answer (score 16):

Another method

Cancel local git repository(Warning: This removes the history)

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then; Create git repostory again

```
git init
```

Then; Repeat the remote repo connect

```
git remote add origin REPO_URL
```

A warning though: This removes the history.

Comment: worked like a charm for me. It's not the prettiest way of doing it, but the git remote rm was not working ... and the suggestion at the github page didn't work either. Thanks

Comment: but then you loose all the history, right? in that case, why not pull in the code from the other/new repository?

Comment: yes, it does remove the whole history. @Yasin should add some kind of warning with the answer.

Comment: Yeah, good solution if you want to also get rid of remote history, otherwise stick to other answers :)

Comment: I do not recommend doing this, if you want to maintain the commit history

Answer (score 16):

perhaps I am late 
you can use `git remote remove origin` it will do the job.

Answer (score 8):

first will change push remote url

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://newurl
```

second will change fetch remote url

```
git remote set-url origin https://newurl
```

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the **.git** folder, edit the config file without using the commands.

Answer (score 2):

**Git aliases** has been life saver:

**Note:**
Default name **origin** if it is different than update according to your needs. I usually have "origin" for all repos

**Step-1:** Define **git** aliases ->

This command will help to view your existing "origin" and remote "URL"

```
 git config --global alias.url "remote -v"
```

This will remove your existing remote "origin"

```
git config --global alias.ro "remote remove origin"
```

This will add new remote "origin"

```
git config --global alias.ao "remote add origin"
```

**Step-2:** How to use it ->

- open your terminal having git repo
- check **existing** origin/ url by running command

```
git url

e.g output:

IF-PERSONAL REPO:

git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO-NAME>.git (fetch/push)


IF-ORGANIZATION:

origin  git@github.com:<ORGANIZATION>/<REPO-NAME>.git (fetch/push)
```

- Remove **existing** origin and url by running command

```
git ro
```

- Add **new** remote origin by running command

```
git ao <URL>

e.g git ao git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO-NAME>.git
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Well, This method and technique worked fine for me: 
Inside the .git folder of your project directory, change these files: 
1 -> configs file 
  -> open it up 
  -> change the ref URL to the remote one. 
 (You must also set your remote origin 
  branch the same as the local 
  branch here inside this file. e.g: remote: main, local: main
 ) 
2 -> git fetch 
3 -> .git 
  -> refs 
  -> heads && remotes folder 
  -> make sure both in files, origins are the same inside both heads and 
    remotes folders. e.g: main or master
4 -> .git 
  -> refs 
  -> remotes 
  -> main 
  -> open it up: 
   Copy the content and paste it inside the main file of the heads 
   folder.

Finally: 
Git fetch && git pull && git push
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me as I had a global origin set, which seemed to override everything in all my repos. In the end, I just edited the .gitconfig file in C:\Users\user_name.