# Invalid Git RSA key fingerprint

Tags: git, github

I started getting this error

```
Received disconnect from 192.30.253.112 port 22:2: Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.
Disconnected from 192.30.253.112 port 22
```

when I tried to commit in git.
Quick googling suggested me to *remove the data* in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and try.
When I removed the data in known hosts and tried 'git pull'

I got this.

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ObNq2tWLML/5O9W4GkU6sqOH5e3KNdxtxT3KU1/9gok.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)
```

However the RSA key fingerprint that I got did not match with the ones given by [github](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/)

If I give yes and continue I am getting this error.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

What should I do now?

Not able to commit or pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the hash does not match, it means that the server you're communicating with sent a different key. Github would probably not change keys without a salient public warning. So, the server is a different server impersonating github server. It could be an evil attacker and/or a corporate proxy.

- [Stéphane Gourichon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710120/the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-192-30-252-128-cant-be-established/35259755?noredirect=1#comment94828134_35259755)