# Trying to upgrade typescript but getting "The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established"

Tags: typescript, github, npm, ssh, npm-install

I'm trying to upgrade my versino of typescript using npm.  I tried running this command

```
localhost:Pastebin davea$ npm install typescript/2.8.4 --save-dev
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.0d71
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session b2dfb7a6e65c0d71
```

But get the error you see above.  I'm unclear why authenticity of github.com can't be established.  The site is up from what I can tell.  Not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: You probably don't have at all or have outdated CA bundle.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/18710120/6309

Comment: This works once you fix the command `npm install typescript@2.8.4 --save-dev` pay attention to `@` instead of `/`. Also this is pretty old version I have to say

Answer (score 0):

I was installing `react-native-community/masked-view` but I was missing the scope `@` in the beginning and it was giving me this error.