# npm install -g aws-amplify/cli gives The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established

Tags: github, ssh, aws-amplify

In an attempt to run sudo npm install -g aws-amplify/cli ,
I am given the error `The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established`

After reading [The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.128)' can't be established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710120/the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-192-30-252-128-cant-be-established), I ran ssh -T git@github.com and get a Permission denided (publickey). Error.
Now if I run the aws-amplify install again, I get:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/aws-amplify/cli.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/matthewmathias/.npm/_logs/2021-03-20T23_41_46_515Z-debug.log
```

Help?

M

Answer (score 0):

Start at least by completing your known_hosts:

```
ssh-keyscan -Ht rsa github.com,192.30.255.112 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

(Although you might want to [double-check the fingerprint with `nmap` first](https://serverfault.com/a/808665/783))

Second, try `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see what keys are considered.
Make sure to have for instance a [`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` registered to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Alternatively, force npm to use HTTPS URLs:

```
 git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```