Ssh does not use keys in ssh agent
SSH simply refuses to use the keys inside of the ssh-agent. Yes i have verified that the keys are in the agent and that the ssh agent is running. I have also set IdentitiesOnly to no in the ssh_config.
running ssh -vT git@github.com returns no errors
Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/20-systemd-ssh-proxy.conf
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_rsa type 3
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/freren/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-3546998e7
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-3546998e7
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/freren/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.


The problem is not with user keys, the problem is with the host key. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69960780/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+authenticity+of+host+github.com+can%27t+be+established

@phd I love you..... THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH

could you please make answer so i can make it as solved @phd
