# How do I remove a remote from git?

Tags: git, smartgit

I use SmartiGit for an SVN repo and now I have this error message in SmartGit:

> The repository has multiple remotes defined (either Git or SVN). This
>   kind of configuration is not supported and will result in errors.

How can I see the multiple remotes and delete the one that is wrong?

```
git remote
```

shows just

```
master
```

I think I added the master remote on the console once and I guess, that is what I did wrong. (I cant recall, how I added it)

Comment: With SmartGit 4.6, you are able to have one SVN remote and additional Git remotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove remote origin from git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`git remote` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

```
git remote remove master
```

But first, do a `git config -l` to see your remote definition, and check if indeed you have a remote named `master` (and where it was pointing to).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, (although I didn't notice any problems while I had that errormessage, don't know what could have occured)