# How to remove remote origin from Mercurial repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo) I'm trying to disconnect my hg repository from a dead remote location, while keeping the local version control.

What is the hg equivalent of `git remote remove origin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handwork: remove obsoleted line from the `[path]` section of the repository configuration file, `.hg/hgrc` (and maybe related credentials from `[auth]`, either in `.hg/hgrc` or `~/.hgrc`).