# Delete all remote tracking branches for a remote git repository

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I somehow added a fork as a remote to my local repository and later on I issued `git pull` - to my dismay git pulled all fork branches as local tracking branches. How can I undo this with one command ? All branches show in gitk as `remote/wr/branchname`

Do I then have to remove the entry from `.git/config` ?

```
[remote "wr"]
    url = https://github.com/AUTHOR/wrye-bash.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/wr/*
```

Comment: Why a -1 ? The command for one branch would be `git branch -rd wr/branchname` - it's a legitimate question to ask for a command that does the same for all wr branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a bit of experimentation (I am not a console person):

```
git branch -rd $( git branch -r | grep 'wr/' )
```

Now if only I could add a dry run switch...

Comment: Removing the wr remote just needed [`git remote remove wr`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16330711/281545)