# git: can't seem to delete remote

Tags: git

I cloned a global project

```
git clone https://github.com/lornajane/scripts.git scripts
```

And I added remote <s>branch</s>

```
git remote add gitlab  http://ankits@abc.xyz/janedoe/my.git
git push gitlab master -f
```

Now the problem is I don't have http://ankits@abc.xyz/janedoe/my.git project anymore on gitlab.

So when I tried deleting remote <s>branch</s>

```
git push gitlab --delete master
```

I got error:

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: 
remote: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To http://ankits@abc.xyz/janedoe/my.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

How do remove this remote. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove remote origin from git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the remote repo with `git remote` with `add` so you can remove it with `rm`. Try `git remote --help` for a full listing.

`git remote rm gitlab` should work for what you wanna do.

Comment: Hi Bily, That seems to work! I can't seem to understand difference between using git remote rm and git push <origin> --delete. Any help understanding

Comment: So the former `git remote rm` just removes the reference to the remote repo. Your `--delete` physically deletes that branch off the face of the earth FOREVER. One is removing a link. The second one is phycally removing the existence of that repo/branch

Comment: The rm is like deleting a symbolic link in a unix directory. Your `--delete` is like `cd`ing to that symbolic link and deleting the directory and all of its contents.

Comment: Thanks...make sense now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the current remote "HEAD" branch..