# Removing a remote repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I had created a private repo on bitbucket and been pushing my changes to it, but I decided to delete it.

Now, every time I make a commit, I am prompted to push, of course...

How do I change/fix this in SourceTree, so that I don't get the prompt and push icon (upward arrow) in my local SourceTree app?

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to do that in bitbucket, but see here how to do it from command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested a remote origin deletion with SourceTree 3.4.5:

You can remove the remote origin, then recreate it: your master branch will then push to the right one.

[image: remove origin on SoruceTree]