# How can I return to using https instead of ssh

Tags: maven-3, bitbucket

I was trying to configure [jgitflow](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/maven-jgitflow-plugin) plugin for my maven project and I have added `<scm>` tag to my `pom.xml`. However initially I have used ssh url instead of https url and since then (even when I remove `<scm>` tag or change the url to https) I get either this:

```
[adam@deathstar myproject]$ git push
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (207.223.240.181)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
```

or this:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I return to using https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution myself.
I had to edit config file: `.git/config`.

In `[core]` section I had to change value of `url` to use `https://username@bitbucket.org` instead of `git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: The cleaner solution would be the following command:

`git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here`

But yours works as well. ;-)

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/598560