# git - switch central repositories

Tags: git

we are migrating from clear case to git.
During this migration I have set a repository on my personal computer and let 5 more people to clone my repo.

I am supposed to get a server dedicated to git in a month.
How can switch the central repository these people to the repository on the site?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a remote repository URI using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Possible duplicate question [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

By telling them to execute the command

```
git remote set-url origin <theNewUrl>
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Answer (score 0):

The default pull/push remote is called 'origin'. You can view these remotes by typing `git remote`. With the additional `-v` you'll also see the URIs of the remotes.

When you want to set a new URI for a remote you can use `git remote set-url [remote-name] [new-url]`. For example `git set-url origin ssh://x@example.com`. See http://gitref.org/remotes/ for more ;-)