# Not able to push commit to GitHub through visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

I recently added github capabilities to Visual Studio. I started a new repo and hooked it up to VS. I have ssh authentication. I successfully did a first commit with the initial project.

Then, from visual studio, I branched the project. I made some changes and committed them.

For some reason, I cannot push them back to git. The <kbd>push</kbd> and <kbd>pull</kbd> buttons on VS are grayed out. According to the tutorial I should now be able to just push <kbd>push</kbd> and it will push (that's a lot of pushes... *ha ha*)

I've attached a screen clipping.

Anyone know what went wrong? I can log into github and see the repo, but the new branch isn't there and no changes are being registered.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to configure the https/ssl endpoint for GitHub, not the ssh endpoint. Visual Studio doesn't support the SSH endpoint yet, even though LibGit2 supports it, due to license issues.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the SSH endpoint, configure your remote to use the https/ssl endpoint instead. Visual Studio, as of yet, doesn't support SSH endpoints due to license restrictions. You can do this by cloning the repository from that endpoint.

[image: GitHub & SSL]

Or if you have commits waiting to be pushed in your local repository, you [can overwrite the remote uri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/736079).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: Ah thank you... The link you added was just what I need. Thanks very much!

Comment: In that case please accept the answer and if you like it, upvote it as well. That tells others that your question has been answered.