# How to change GitHub repository in IDEA Intellij?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, project

I've lost access to my previous account on GitHub, so created new one and now, when I am trying to share my project ( which was shared on GitHub before), I get this message:

```
Can't get repository info: {myRepositoryName}
404: Not Found - Not Found
```

How to tell IDEA Intellij that I want to share project on different repository? thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TO CHANGE GITHUB CREDENTIALS**

**From an open project:**

*File > Settings > [Project Settings] > Version Control > GitHub*

Or

*File > Other Settings > Default Settings > [Template Project Settings] > Version Control > GitHub*

**From the Welcome Screen**

*Configure > Settings > [Template Project Settings] > Version Control > GitHub*

**TO CHANGE THE GIT REPOSITORY**

This needs to be done via command line or the Terminal Tool Window in IDEA (*Tools > Terminal Window*). See Stackoverflow topic [How to change a remote repository URI using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git) for information.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed, I have changed credentials before, but didnt' know how to change repository URI

Comment: How to change the BitBucket repository URL. In the Bitbucket Linky plugin I do not see an option to modify the existing repository url.

Answer (score 71):

**Update or add Git repository URL in Intellij**

**VCS - > Git - > Remotes**

Popup will open with all repository URLs configured, you can simply edit them or add new one.

Answer (score 11):

As of 2021 IntelliJ versions, this is now called "Manage Remotes" not just "Remotes"

[image]

Copy in the clone URL from github/bitbucket etc...

[image]