# IntelliJ IDEA keeps trying to Auto fetch a deleted repository

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I deleted some repository from GitHub. and IntelliJ IDEA keeps trying to Auto fetch them.
I'm constantly I get this error message:

*9:06 PM    Auto fetch failed
origin: remote: Repository not found.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Guilderm/skypos.git/'
Development: remote: Repository not found.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Guilderm/Skypos.git/'
master and Dev: remote: Repository not found.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Guilderm/Skopos.git/'
github: remote: Repository not found.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Guilderm/Sypos.git/'*

each time this happens, I get a pop asking me for a password and have to enter it 3 to 4 times, despite having the remember password check

I have created a new project and looked at Settings Repository:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-settings-repository.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `git remote rm origin`

This command will delete the local reference to the remote repository. Intellij should be smart enough to pick up on that and stop fetching.

If that doesn't work, try going to the menu option listed here: [How to change GitHub repository in IDEA Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241509/how-to-change-github-repository-in-idea-intellij)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to Update the Git repository URL in Intellij:

VCS - > Git - > Remotes

A Popup will open with all repository URLs configured, you can simply edit, add or remove them.

Refrence:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884691/5734815