# linked local repo to incorrect github account

Tags: git, github

As part of the Coursera Data Scientist course set up, I incorrectly linked a directory, test-repo, to an incorrect account. So, in the statement:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUserNamehere/test-repo.git
```

I incorrectly specified the User Name. I'm thinking that I can delete the directory and reset it up again. I've researched the ability to either delete the directory or re-link it to the right account but have not found any information that can help me do so. Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: you want to change your origin url to another link? just run git remote add origin your_url again, it will override it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: @Joe a certain duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

To change the URL of a remote, use `git remote set-url <name> <newurl>`,
in your example

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/yourUserNamehere/test-repo.git
```

Removing the remote and then adding it again as suggested in the comment by @xwhyLikeThis would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the existing remotes by the above command.

```
git remote -v
```

Then to reset the remote URL,you can do the following:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

To verify the new remote URL, you can type the first command again:

```
git remote -v
```