# How do I reuse my old Github repository name?

Tags: github

#### I made a Github repository and named it

I created a Github repository named, let's say, `my-first-repository` under a username, let's call it `MyFirstUsername` so the entire URL path might look something like:

First Github Path

```
https://github.com/MyFirstUsername/my-first-repository
```

---

#### Then I changed accounts

At some later time, I created a second account for whatever reason. Let's call it `MySecondUsername` Now, I can't access the first account but I want to upload an update to my first repository located at:

```
https://github.com/MySecondUsername/my-first-repository
```

---

#### Question

> **Is there a way to get the first account to "release" the namespace? Or any other way to use the first repository name even if it's going to reside in a separate (the second) account's repository?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change url

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/MySecondUsername/my-first-repository
```

refer:[Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)