# Cloning from a repo then pushing to a different one

Tags: git

I'm using WordPress Sage so for every project I clone their repo. For my current project I want to push to a repo of mine though. Should I delete all Git files and start over, or can I keep them and somehow inform Git about my repo?

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new remote.

```
git remote add myrepo myuser@myserver
git push myrepo mybranch
```

If you want `mybranch` to always push to myrepo, change the tracking information:

```
git push -u myrepo mybranch
```

Comment: When doing "git remote add origin https://github.com/my_account/my_repo.git" I get "fatal: remote origin already exists.". I tried to delete my repo but still got the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: @drake035 Do not name it `origin`. Name it `myrepo`, literally.

Comment: Thanks, worked (no error message this time). Then I did "git push" and it tried to push to old repo. Argh :(

Comment: @drake035 Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the remote repo. See [Git Basics | Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

`git remote add origin /path-or-URL/to-repo`

Comment: When doing "git remote add origin github.com/my_account/my_repo.git"; I get "fatal: remote origin already exists.".

Comment: @drake035 replace origin with another name.