# How to switch to a new remote git repository

Tags: git, github

I've recently cloned a repo to my local drive, but now I'm trying to push all changes to a complete new repo. However, git keeps telling me that permission is denied, and that's because it's trying to push to the originally-cloned repo.

DETAILS:

I originally cloned from https://github.com/taylonr/intro-to-protractor (i.e. based on a Pluralsight course at https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/protractor-introduction/table-of-contents ) .

Now that I've completed the course, I'd like to push my finalized code up to my own git repo (which I just created on github):

https://github.com/robertmazzo/intro-to-protractor

When I use the following git command:

> git remote add origin https://github.com/robertmazzo/intro-to-protractor.git

it tells me `remote origin already exists` , which I guess is fine because I already created it on github.com.

However, when I push my changes up I'm getting an exception.

> git push origin master

`remote: Permission to taylonr/intro-to-protractor.git denied to robertmazzo.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/taylonr/intro-to-protractor.git/':
The requested URL returned error: 403`

So I'm investigating how I can switch to my new repository, but this is exactly where my issue is. I cannot figure this part out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 28):

To change your current origin to a new one, use:

```
git remote set-url origin <url>
```

Source:
https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Answer (score 17):

Before you can add a new remote named "origin", you need to either delete the old one, or simply rename it if you still need access to it for some reason.

```
# Pick one
git remote remove origin            # delete it, or ...
git remote rename origin old-origin # ... rename it

# Now you can add the new one
git remote add origin https://github.com/robertmazzo/intro-to-protractor.git
```

Answer (score 9):

**origin** is only an alias to identify your remote repository.

You can create a new remote reference and push

```
git remote add new_origin https://github.com/robertmazzo/intro-to-protractor.git
git push new_origin master
```

If you want to remove the previous reference

```
git remote remove origin
```

Answer (score 3):

Either add a new remote

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

or, if you completely want to remove the old `origin`, first do

```
git remote remove origin
```

and then

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

Note that the message `remote origin already exists` is not fine. It tells you that the operation *failed*, i.e. it could not set the new remote.