# How to deploy that web dev project on GitHub which is already deployed on Heroku?

Tags: github

earlier I deployed my app on Heroku without deploying it on Github, now I was trying to deploy it on GitHub using GitHub desktop but it starts fetching it from Heroku and not deploying on Github.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch to a new remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351604/how-to-switch-to-a-new-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the GitHub repository address here:
  [image: clone button]
- Add it to your "remotes" repositories with:
  `git remote add https://github.com/your_repository_url`
- Push to GitHub with:
  `git push origin main`