# Push to github from local, cloned from another repo

Tags: git, github

If you have already cloned someone else's repo (rather than forking) and have been committing locally, what's the appropriate way to push that into a new remote repo on GitHub?

Comment: Is the remote repo a fork (clicking the fork button on GitHub) or a new empty repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the remote or add another one.

To change the remote

```
git remote set-url origin https://www.something.com/my_repo.git
```

To add a secondary remote as e.g. `other_origin`

```
git remote add other_origin https://www.something.com/my_repo.git
```

If you changed `origin` you can `git push` to the new remote. If you added another remote, you can specify during `git push` which remote you want to push to.