# Git push local repository with all branches as-is to remote repository

Tags: git

I want to make my local version of a repository (not a single branch, all branches) the new remote version.

Is there a way how to do that or do I have to overwrite/add each branch manually? It is not an initial commit. I just want to overwrite everything that is online with a local version that is more correct than the one currently online (after some bad git operations I want to restore it with a backup version).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
git push origin --mirror
```

From the [manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---mirror)

> `--mirror`
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, **specifies that all refs** under `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote repository. **Newly created local refs will be pushed** to the remote end, **locally updated refs will be force updated** on the remote end, and **deleted refs will be removed** from the remote end. This is the default if the configuration option `remote.<remote>.mirror` is set.

(emphasis mine)