# Can't push an android studio project into github

Tags: android, git, github, version-control

I had some existing repositories on github and i deleted them, now i want to reshare my project into github the android studio but i get this error

JustJava2: failed with error: fatal: repository not found

How can i make android studio to create a new repository and push the project their?

Comment: What steps produced this error? Please describe how you created the GitHub repo (you can even provide a link) and the local repo. Either show the commands you typed or describe the actions you performed in Android Studio. Screenshots can also help supplement your verbal descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, please check the github repo URL in android studio.

   Android studio -> click Terminal -> input the command `git remote –v` to check the github repo URL you were working.

   [image]

   Assume the URL you found is https://github.com/username/r2 (or https://github.com/username/r2.git).
2. Then create a new repo with the same name (such as r2).

   Click + icon -> New repository -> name the same repo name (r2) as you found in above step -> Create repository.

   [image]

   If you have already create a new repo with different name or there is no output for `git remote –v` in the first step, you can set remote url in android studio terminal by `git remote set-url origin <the new created repo URL>`.
3. Now you can push your project successful in android studio.

Comment: really appreciated the `git remote set-url origin <url>` response

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a new remote repository and updated the local repos remote url? You can see how to change the remote url from the command line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)