# Ssh github + gitlab, how to make?

Tags: git, ssh

I want to not type my username and password every time when work with something git, so my ssh config is:

```
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
   IdentitiesOnly yes


Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I makes 2 different rsa keys, add pub keys to github and gitlab, but it keep asking me login and pass, pls can someone help me with it?

Comment: It's asking me on only https protocol i think, tryed to git clone git@gitlab.com:some/some.git and it's not ask my password, so how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the project directory and type `git config --list`.

If `remote.origin.url` looks like `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git`, you will need to change it to the one that looks like `git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git`. This can be found on the main page of any project on GitLab.

Use [git-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to set the new URL.

`git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298943/7691151) shows an example of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Git provides two methods to reduce this repitition:

1. Static configuration of usernames for a given authentication context.
2. Credential helpers to cache or store passwords, or to interact with a system password wallet or keychain.

The first is simple and appropriate if you do not have secure storage available for a password. It is generally configured by adding this to your config:

`[credential "https://example.com"]
 username = me`

Credential helpers, on the other hand, are external programs from which Git can request both usernames and passwords; they typically interface with secure storage provided by the OS or other programs.

To use a helper, you must first select one to use. Git currently includes the following helpers:

cache - Cache credentials in memory for a short period of time.
store - Store credentials indefinitely on disk.

Please go through this for detailed info: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials