# Moving multiple files into new folder and updating GitHub URL

Tags: git, github

I have a React app saved in a GitHub repository (`git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO-OLD.git`). I would like to move all my files in REPO-OLD into a new folder called REPO-NEW:

**REPO-NEW > REPO-OLD > React app**

How do I update it and replace my GitHub remote URL accordingly (i.e. pushing the project from `REPO-NEW` instead of `REPO-OLD`)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to move it only locally? The GitHub repo remains the same? If yes, then just rename the folder. Git repository artefacts are stored in `.git` folder. Doesn't matter what the name of your folder is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's very similar, but when I tried to do `git remote set-url origin repo-new` I get the error message `fatal: No such remote 'origin'`

Comment: You probably need to add it then?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added origin but when I try to push, the following message appears - `error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO-NEW.git. Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.` But when I try to do a git pull, another error pops up - `refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: How did you create your new remote repo? Is it empty?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO-NEW.git`

Comment: That’s how you added it as “origin”. How did you create the repo REMOTE-NEW?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I created a repo for REMOTE-OLD with `hub create`, is it possible to rename/update that repo instead of making a new one for REMOTE-NEW?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/renaming-a-repository?