# Having trouble reconnecting a Visual Studio Solution to GIT after my network got rearranged

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a GIT online repository for a Visual Studio Solution, but the IT people here completely reorganized the network and I lost my local repository. My sourcecode has some changes that aren't yet pushed, so I don't want to lose those. However, all attempts to connect my source to the repository have failed.

I am the only developer on the project, so I'm not worried on other people's code, just getting mine checked in.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm happy to give whatever additional information is needed.

Comment: On what server does the remote repo live? One on your company's network, or on the Internet? What happens when you try to pull or push?

Comment: Update the remote URL with the one you get to clone the repository (are you using Azure Devops?)

Comment: So you have everything local but just can't connect to remote to push  your changes? You just need to update remote URL in that case.

Comment: @CodeCaster Internet on GitHub. I'm not the repository owner, but I am a user.

Comment: @Philippe I'm not using Azure Devops. I can't seem to connect to the remote but I think it's just me not understanding.

Comment: @Ppp Using the Team Exporer in Visual Studio, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: You can edit the remote from
Team Explorer -> Settings -> Repository Settings

Comment: @Ppp I only see Global Settings, no Repository Settings in Team Explorer -> Settings

Comment: Interesting. I see it on mine! You could try setting remote url from command line. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/4594986

Comment: @Ppp I tried another project and was able to set to the remote, but now I am getting the following error: "Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again."

Comment: Hmm... I guess your remote has new commits that your local branch doesn't. Instead of doing a push you may wanna do a pull so you can merge remote into local.