# Change git repo from remote host

Tags: laravel, git, vue.js, phpstorm, digital-ocean

I have **laravel-vue.js** framework web site project that another developer coded on **digitalocean**.

Also there is a **git** file in the framework.

I want to use **git**, too. However, there is another **git ssh link** in project.

```
git@gitlab.com:user/projectname.git
```

I created a gitlab repo but i couldn't decide what to do next.

```
git@gitlab.com:myuser/projectname2.git
```

How can i get this project to my local and do changes on git.

Generally i use **phpstorm** for coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your git origin url in your repository.

Use `git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here` to replace old git URL with the new one.

Comment: You can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository for more details