# How do I change the communication protocol of an existing repo to ssh from https for gitlab?

Tags: git

I have a repository which I cloned with `https` instead of `ssh`. Now everytime I change the system password, I'm required to update it in the credential manager. So I generated `ssh` key and added on the local as well as remote repository to establish `ssh` communication. The problem is it still says `basic authentication failed` if I try running a command, such as `git fetch` or `git push`, which require establishing a connection with the server . Seems like once we are cloning a repository with `https`, we're not able to change it to follow the `ssh` protocol. Is there a way to navigate around that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+change+remote+URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the remote URL by using `git remote set-url`.
If HTTPS it should be something like this: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`
If SSH:
`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`.
More info [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url)