# turning a fork to a new branch of an existing branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow

Consider that you have a repository `https://gitlab.com/my_repo` with at least two branches `Master` and `Develop`. You have forked the repo into a private one `https://gitlab.com/my_repo_fork`. You have applied some edits to the `Master` branch. Now you want to turn the local `Master` into a new branch of the original repo, branched from the `Develop` branch. So What I have

- `https://gitlab.com/my_repo`

  - `Master`
  - `Develop`
- `https://gitlab.com/my_repo_fork`

  - `Master`* (edited)
  - `Develop`

and what I want to have:

- `https://gitlab.com/my_repo`

  - `Master`
  - `Develop`
  - `|-> Improvment/number` (from the edited `Master`*)

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the safest way to do this. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a branch from `master`, commit the changes and rebase the branch onto the develop branch and then solve merge conflicts:

On `master`

```
git checkout -b Improvement/number // create the new branch and add changes
git add .
git commit -m "<message>
git rebase Develop                 // rebase the new branch onto Develop
```

Initially, the new branch contains the changes from master:

```
https://gitlab.com/my_repo_fork

Master (now clean)
|-> Improvment/number
Develop
```

The rebase removes ("cuts") the branch from `master` and applies the changes to `Develop`:

```
Master (now clean)
Develop
|-> Improvment/number
```

For a description with better graphics see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: The `rebase` option turns the local `Master`* into a branch from `Develop`? and then I can push to the original repo?

Comment: Basically, yes. It reverts the changes from the newly created branch and tries to apply them to the `Develop` branch.

Comment: I will try this and report here.

Comment: How do I change the `origin` of the local repo, cloned from `https://gitlab.com/my_repo_fork` to `https://gitlab.com/my_repo`?

Comment: I think the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/4999991)