# How to specify the branch you want to merge to on GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771382/turning-a-fork-to-a-new-branch-of-an-existing-branch), consider that you have a repo with this configuration:

```
https://gitlab.com/my_repo
                    |-> firstBranch
                    |-> secondBranch
                           |-> token/ticket
```

Now I want to create a merge request to a specific branch `firstBranch`. Looking at the [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html), I can't see that option:

```
   [][3]  
(source: [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/new_merge_request_page_v12_6.png))
```

does it mean if I create a merge request it will be merged into the `secondBranch`? if that's the case then I can `rebase` the `token/ticket` branch to `firstBranch` and then create the merge request. However, I was wondering if there is a way to ask for a direct merge on GitLab web-app UI? Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a "change branches" link on the top of the GUI. Click it, and choose the branch you want to merge in to:

[image]

Comment: are there any options to modify the former merge requests while they are not processed? I think I have made a mistake :)

Comment: @Foad If you edit the merge request, you should get a similar dialog, and can choose to have the MR against a different branch.

Comment: but how do you edit a merge request? [this](https://i.imgur.com/C5N6HUJ.png) is what I see at the moment.

Comment: @Foad from the search, there don't see to be any MRs assigned to you. Perhaps they are assigned to someone else (which makes sense if you created them and are waiting for someone to review them)