# How to change url of Git repository for all branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I git clone my old repository.

I list all branch:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/master
  origin/release/1.1.0
  origin/support/1.0.0
  origin/support/1.0.2
```

I change url:

```
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.xx:1234/xxx-xxx/xxxxxxxx.git
```

I push code in new repository:

```
$ git push -f
```

My result is OK for `master` branch but I want all branch find by `git branch -r`. How to do please?

**EDIT** (but only `master` branch is present in my new Bitbucket):

I try

```
git push --all
```

I try

```
git pull --all
git push --all
```

I try

```
git pull --all
git pull --mirror
git push --mirror
git push --all
```

Comment: Did you check on and try `git push --all` in the documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: @matt, you link ask only one branch. I read this solution (use in my case), but I have only `master` branch in my new repository.

Comment: @sgrillon I think if you look through the answers _and comments_ on that page, you will find that what you're asking is quite well answered. For example, it tells you about `git push --all`.

Comment: @matt, I try `git push --all` but this command create a new branch named 'list'. (no push all branch to my new bitbucket):   `[new branch]      list -> list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they aren't being pushed is that these are remote branches that only exist on your original remote, not in your local repository (that's why the suggestions of `git push --all` aren't working).

As there are only a few, I suggest you simply checkout the ones you want locally and then redo the push. e.g.

```
git checkout release/1.1.0
git checkout support/1.0.2
git push --all
```

That will do it. There is a way to push all branches up, but I'd need to test it so this will fix the issue for now.

Comment: is it possible git checkout all branch?