# How to update the git repo in package.json

Tags: git, github, npm, gitlab, package.json

While setting up my project I had set up my repo in GitLab. Now I have migrated to GitHub by importing the repository. All the history (commits) has been imported successfully. But now when I add new commits, those are still shown in GitLab and not updated in GitHub. How do I link my project to GitHub and cut its ties with GitLab?

```
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "git+https://gitlab.com/username/projectname.git"
},
"bugs": {
"url": "https://gitlab.com/username/projectname/issues"
},
 "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/username/projectname#readme"
```

This is how my package.json looks as of now

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: `origin https://gitlab.com/username/projectname.git (fetch)`
`origin https://gitlab.com/username/projectname.git (push)`

Comment: The answer is there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score -1):

Vanilla git does not store the remote repository location in the package.json. Use this command to change the remote repository:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/project.git`

(You'll have to update the username and project)