# How do I overwrite the origin of my git repo

Tags: git

I'd like to overwrite the origin of my git repo (I moved it from my company account to personal account).

When I do `git remote add origin` it complains that the origin already exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: When the error message already exists *down to the branch* we don't need another Q&A pair.

Answer (score 0):

You change the location of your remote origin with `git remote set-url origin <new-url-here>`

More info can be found in the docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the target URL by doing

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin ORIGIN
git config master.remote origin
git config master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Replace `ORIGIN` with your origin

Example

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:tolicodes/infragen.git
git config master.remote origin
git config master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Comment: `git remote set-url`?

Comment: before posting a question and its reply, please check carefully your question hasn't already been answered elsewhere, as pointed out in the comments