# Remove git from project xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, github

[image]I have created a project with git many years ago. But it doesn't contain all the files.
Currently I would like to add all files of that project to git with a new account. But while trying to commit it says "The repository is locked" . After doing a research I found need to remove .git folder from project so I ran `rm -f .git/index.lock`. But unable to remove the existing git from project. How can I delete the existing git from project.

Edit

Iam able to delete the git folder now and create a new git. But two separate repositories are create (one for the project) and other for Pods. How to create a single repository for the whole project

Comment: If you do `ls -la` on the folder of your project, does `.git`, and `.gitignore` appearsN Light want to remove them. But you also could just change the target url of the project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository etc. You can open it in SourceTree or other app with GUI that allow you to modify the URLs, access, account, etc if you prefer.

Comment: @Larme If I do ls -la on the project folder I dont get .git and .gitignore

Comment: Say `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find the git folder.

Comment: @matt It doesnt show any path of git folder when I do above

Comment: @Honey You don't have to worry about it, you are not going to commit the POD files. If you still want to please delete .git folders inside Pods directory.

Comment: @Satheesh Your suggestion helped me and I m able to use git now for my app. Thank you.

Comment: @Honey Glad it did, please accept my answer if you feel so.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to remove git from the project and then re-initalize it.

```
rm -rf .git*
```

Then

```
git init
git add *
```

Comment: When I do rm -rf .git* I get the error zsh: no matches found: .git* in terminal

Comment: Try this  find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf

Comment: searches and shows "Operation not permitted" in terminal

Comment: Yes Am in current directory . xargs: unterminated quote is the error

Comment: can you just do rm -rf .git ? and tell me what is happening.

Comment: Nothing happens .

Comment: and when you do ls what is the output do you see the .git folder?

Comment: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder I have used this to find hidden files of mac found here https://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/ and able to delete .git file now. I have one more doubt . can u please clarify it . My project has appfiles along with pods. When I create new git repositories two separate remote repositories are created. How is it possible to make it as a single one as it belongs to single project only .

Comment: Please check the attached image in my question

Comment: Don't try the suggestion of "Try this find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf", it'll delete the entire project folder