# flutter upgrade is not working in vs code giving improper url as well?

Tags: flutter, dart, github, visual-studio-code, version-control

This is the error log am getting when i try to upgrade flutter

```
[flutter] flutter upgrade
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/marzookavc/flutter.git/' not found
Command: git fetch --tags
exit code 1
```

flutter.git is not my project name how to change the url

committing and pushing is working perfectly!
and cannot change the channel also

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/14231239

Comment: git remote -v is showing my correct github path

Comment: You can use `git remote set-url origin you-git-url.git`

Comment: yes i have corrected my url , its correct then also this error coming

Comment: Let me know what you exactly wan,  to update your flutter or your project from git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to upgrade your flutter version, but the current folder that store your flutter framework is pointing to `'https://github.com/marzookavc/flutter.git/'`, maybe you forked a repository from the original Flutter repo before, but it's not accessible now.

To use and upgrade Flutter correctly, the fastest way is just to redownload the Flutter package [from here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install). It will have correct config that save you time in debugging the correct origin link of the repo

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you may have cloned a fork of the Flutter repository and then subsequently deleted it. Assuming you made no changes/commits, you should be able to fix it by updating the `remote` to the official Flutter repo:

```
# In your *Flutter SDK* folder (not your project) in a terminal
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: mine does show the right git repo, but still not able to upgrade `unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset` and I do have connection

Answer (score 0):

Between Bach and dm_tr, they have what I think is the correct answer.
It looks like you have installed flutter from `https://github.com/marzookavc/flutter.git/`.

Which means when you run flutter upgrade it is trying to connect to that repository to pull in the latest changes.
So if you do not want to do as Bach suggests and simply reinstall flutter on your machine as per the recommended methods.

You can change the remote for your flutter install.
So for example if you have flutter installed at.
`~/flutter`
You will need to go to that directory, check the git remotes and change them accordingly.

As an example in the directory where I have flutter installed, the remotes look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved this by forking to this link: [flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)

after that run again: `flutter upgrade` in your project terminal

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the following installation bundle to get the latest stable release of the Flutter SDK:
   https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows
2. Extract the zip file and place the contained flutter in the desired installation location for the Flutter SDK (for example, C:\src\flutter).
3. cd C:\src\flutter
4. git remote set-url origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
5. flutter upgrade
6. flutter pub get

done.