# Upgrade Flutter SDK from 3.10.3 to 3.10.5

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to move from Flutter SDK from 3.10.3 to 3.10.5. How can I do that?

Comment: simply write "flutter upgrade"

Comment: I do flutter upgrade but I get this error ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
  Command: git fetch --tags

Comment: hmm strange. No idea why that is

Comment: can you post the entire error after flutter upgrade?

Comment: C:\Users\KS>flutter upgrade --force
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
  Command: git fetch --tags

Comment: [Solved reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65407267/21296112)  This may work!!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with

```
flutter upgrade
```

If not workings try with

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Still if you face any error you can follow the officlal [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade). Else you can directly download the specific sdk from the following [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=macos)

Comment: I do flutter upgrade --force but I get this error ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. Command: git fetch --tags

Comment: you can add the err log in your question itself so that it will be helpful to others to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Flutter Version Management(FVM) for your version management.

You can install any version with it. So you have access to all your versions.

https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/overview

Above is a link to get started. The documentation is straight forward, for both installation and usage.

Answer (score 0):

as you want to go to a specific flutter version flutter upgrade won't work for you.
follow this.

Step 1:
Open the terminal and Navigate to the Flutter location

```
cd [flutter_path]
```

For example, my flutter Location is: `C:\flutter`

so my command will be:

```
cd  C:\flutter
```

change the location with yours.

Step 2:

Now enter the command

```
git checkout [version]
```

as you  want to go to 3.10.5 so for  your case the
the command is:

```
git checkout 3.10.5
```

Step:3

and run  `flutter doctor -v` command so Flutter will download the stuff related to the particular version

your version will be changed depending on your connection speed.
after successfully fetching all the data restart your ide.
hit solved if this worked for you.