# I mistakenly added an unknown repository to git locally in the command line. How do I remove or replace the repository

Tags: git, github, git-repo

I want to remove the wrong repository and replace it with the correct repository on GitHub. What do I do?

```
Fatal: repository "https://GitHub.com/username/alx-pre_school.git" not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have named your repository `origin`, you can check it by running

```
git remote -v
```

The output will look like

```
origin  https://github.com/user/your_repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/your_repo.git (push)
```

To change the remote's repository URL run

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/new_name.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply execute the following command to change the URI:

- HTTPS

  `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`
- SSH

  `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Alternatively, find `.git/config` in the cloned folder structure, look for `[remote "origin"]`, and edit the `url =` assignment.

`.git/config` would look similar to below,

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Verify whether its working by examining the remotes:

```
git remote -v
# origin  git://new.location (fetch)
# origin  git://new.location (push)
```

Next time you push, mention the upstream like below:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Reference: [GitHub: Manage Remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories)

Comment: Thanks @Keshan Nageswaran