# How do I clone single branch from one repo to another, on every commit?

Tags: git, github, gitea

I have a repository under [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) and another one under [GitHub](https://github.com/).
I need to connect these two in a way that: create a dedicated branches in both repositories and connect the branches. For example:

- Gitea repo has a branch: `/send-to-github`
- GitHub repo has a branch: `/receive-from-gitea`

Every time when I push the commit in Gitea, the commit automatically triggers an event that pushes the very same code in the GitHub branch.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: To completely automate this in an easy way, you need to be able to enable Git hooks on the Gitea instance (be mindful because this can have a big security impact). Then you could add a hook which (force) pushes the updated branch to GitHub whenever an update is received.

Answer (score 0):

You can change remote URL as you wish. You can check this answer for more info: [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

So one way to do this would be to create a script that will do the following on every push:

1. push to Gitea repo
2. switch remote url to GitHub repo
3. push to GitHub repo
4. switch remote url back to Gitearepo

Note that this will cause issues when multiple people are using the repo. Basically you would have to duplicate all git actions to work with both repositories.

Other approach could be if GitHub is used as a "backup" repo to create a recurring job that will pull form repo A and force push to repo B

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are aiming at copying (cherry-picking) every commit from `send-to-github` to `receive-from-gitea` branches.

I would assume there are more elegant ways to achieve this, but here is a quick and dirty way to get (I assume) what you want.

There are some prerequisites to cover, such as - have 2 already defined remote URLs (`origin` and `github` as an example).

Create yourself a script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First push to gitea
git push origin send-to-github

# Get the currently pushed commit that you just created and pushed
CURR_COMMIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# Go to your other branch that must go to github
git checkout receive-from-gitea

# Apply the commit so that it is "copied" onto the github branch
git cherry-pick $CURR_COMMIT_SHA

# Push to your github remote repository
git push gitub receive-from-gitea
```

Make it executable and add it as an alias to your git configuration:

```
[alias]
    double-push = "!c() { bash /path/to/script.sh ; }; c"
```

Then once you are ready to commit and push to your Gitea repo, instead of pushing with `git push` use your newly created alias `git double-push` and it should work as intended.