# Error when uploading code to github using visual code

Tags: visual-studio

I have uploaded the code to github with the project name as demo but after I delete the demo project to upload the code to a new project, the code in vscode keeps pushing the code to the deleted project is there any way to fix it?

Comment: 'git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here'

This has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)