# I try to push something on github it show us such error like https://github.com/yashk1877/Portfolio.git/' not found

Tags: github

i was change user name of my github account and now whenever I try to push something on github it show us such error like
**remote: Repository not found.**
**fatal: repository 'https://github.com/yashk1877/Portfolio.git/' not found**
yashk1877 was my old user name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow! You could try changing the github remote, so that git can actually find that remote repository. Make sure you try something on your own before posting a question here.