# Upload a project from one gitHub account to another

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have a project in one GitHub account and I want to upload it to another account without giving access to the first account and the first folder.
I could not find a normal upload option because the old GitHub account has already been embedded on the project.

I tried both Visual Studio and through CMD, maybe there is another option to do it?

Wait for an answer.

I did it: (GitHub instructions)

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/UserName/FolderName.git
```

and get

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: No. it's not working well

Comment: what's the error you are receiving? the solution in the linked article does not suggest using `remote add`