# How to cancel git remote set-url?

Tags: git, url

As described in the accepted answer of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-do-i-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository), we should use

```bash
git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here
```

Personally, I used the `-v` option as well, i.e.

```
git remote -v set-url origin https://gitlab.com/<user_name>/<new_name>
```

However, when I now do

```
git push origin main
```

I'm being asked for git username and password and my credentials don't get accepted. So I want to abort the above command of setting the remote url, how do I do this? (Usually, I'm not being asked for my git username and password when I do `git push`, only for the password of the private key.)

Comment: Just run the command again with the old git url. Or edit `.git/config` and change it manually there.

Comment: @match I did that, but I'm still being asked for username and password, which still don't get accepted. It's ok if the old link is used, but I want it to be as in the past where I did not have to provide username + passwd for git pushes.

Comment: Private key implies you should have an ssh:// url not an https:// one?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this must be it... In my `config` file in `.git`, I have an entry of the form `url = https://gitlab.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git`, can I just change it to `url = git@gitlab.com:<user_name>/<repo_name>.git`?