# How to disconnect my terminal from other remote server in vs code?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-remote

**I had an old project, which I committed to GitHub.**
Then I had a new project and on this one I could reuse some of the old code from the old project. **So I duplicated the folder** and opened it on vscode to rewrite my code.

**The thing is, the terminal on vscode is still connected to the GitHub remote server from the old project and I need to disconnect it and commit it as a new repository on GitHub.**

I researched about it but couldn't really find any case similar to this.

I'm new to this. I know it's probably really basic stuff, but it would be awesome if someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Terminals don't actually "connect" in the way you're describing. Probably all you need to do is change or remove the `remote` for your Git repo. Type `git remote -vv` from the command line to see your current remotes. Note you commit locally, and then push commits to a remote. If all you need is to change your remote for the copy of the repo, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432764/184546). You may be interested in using a fork too (or instead of a new repo).

Comment: Did you copy the `.git` folder with that old project? If you're creating a new repo unrelated to the old one, delete that folder from the copy and start fresh.

Comment: @joanis is right **if you're creating a new repo**. But if you have new work in that repo already, you don't want to delete the `.git` folder.

Comment: @TTT Reading the question, it was my impression that OP is creating a new project in which they want to include a copy of old code but disconnected from their old project.

Comment: @joanis I agree that's the most likely interpretation. I mentioned it just in case they have new commits or other things in the repo they wish to keep.

Comment: First of all, thank you @TTT and @joanis.

When I finally tried to push my commits to the remote repository I got the following message "error: remote origin already exists.".

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I used `git remote -v` to check out to which remote I was "connected" to and noticed it was, indeed, the one from the old project.
2. So, I used `git remote set-url origin https://newurlhere.com` to specify the new repository address.
3. It was only then that I could, once again, use my origin repository to commit my files to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

When I finally tried to push my commits to the remote repository I got the following message "error: remote origin already exists.".

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I used `git remote -v` to check out to which remote I was "connected"
   to and noticed it was, indeed, the one from the old project.
2. So, I used `git remote set-url origin https://newurlhere.com` to
   specify the new repository address.
3. It was only then that I could, once again, use my origin repository
   to commit my files to the correct place.

Here is where I found more information about the error: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/remote-origin-already-exists-error