# github: can fetch and pull but not push

Tags: git, github, ssh

I ran into this situation where I'd cloned one of my own github repositories onto my laptop.  And I can fetch and pull from the repo, but when I try to push changes, I get:

```
% git push
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

This is doomed to failure, since it's trying to use password authentication which github no longer supports.  But to the best of my knowledge, I DO have the proper github certificates set up in my .ssh/ directory.

FWIW, here's what my remote looks like:

```
% git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<my_account>/<my_repo>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<my_account>/<my_repo>.git (push)
```

Comment: For https authentication, Github now requests [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens) instead of password

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from [How do I change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-do-i-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository/2432799).  Here's what happened:

I had created a public repo on my workstation. I then cloned the repo onto my laptop *while I was not logged into github*.  As a result, the repo was created on my laptop with http authentication, not ssh.

The fix is easy: you need to convert your local repo to use ssh authentication, not http:

1. Log into your github account and navigate to the repo in question.
2. Click on the green "<> Code" button.
3. Select the "SSH" tab and copy the offered URI.  It should be something like `git@github.com:<your_account>/<your_repo>.git`
4. In a shell window, navigate to your local repository.
5. Type `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<your_account/<your_repo>.git`

To check the result, use `git remote -v`.  It should look like this:

```
% git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:<your_account/<your_repo>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<your_account/<your_repo>.git (push)
```

Voila.  Now you should be able to push the changes.