# What is the difference between "git whatchanged -- filename" and "git rev-list -- filename"

Tags: git, git-log

What is the difference between the 2 commands below. I see different outputs.
Both are run from a clone having a single branch.

```
git whatchanged -m -- foo.c

git rev-list --reverse --all -- foo.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  mentioned in the [`git whatchanged` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-whatchanged):

> Shows commit logs and diff output each commit introduces.
> The command **internally invokes `git rev-list` piped to `git diff-tree`**, and takes command line options for both of these commands.

The "piped to `git diff-tree`" would explain the different output between both commands.

You can find an example of `git rev-list` combined with a `git diff` in "[In git, how can I get the diff between all the commits that occured between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161609/in-git-how-can-i-get-the-diff-between-all-the-commits-that-occured-between-two)".

---

Update September 2013:

The [new version of the man page for git whatchanged now emphasizes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/992c38644a4b001bdc89b5b5008fc5f6674ed5b7/Documentation/git-whatchanged.txt#L19-L25):

> New users are encouraged to use [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) instead. The `whatchanged` command is essentially the same as [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.
>
> **The command is kept primarily for historical reasons; fingers of many people who learned Git long before `git log` was invented** by reading Linux kernel mailing list are trained to type it.

See more at "[Difference between `git-log` and `git-whatchanged`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10022722/6309)".

Comment: Thanks!, so if i want to see what happened to a file (check for code-loss in merges or something), which command should be the best?

Comment: @SenthilAKumar: if it involves checking the changes of *content*, then `git whatchanged` is a good start. The question I link to in my answer provides other alternatives based on `git diff`.

Comment: @SenthilAKumar: I don't see your edit. Your initial question appears to be untouched.

Comment: Similar question follows on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414940/git-log-and-git-whatchanged-shows-2-commits-but-both-have-same-lines-added-so